# Problemas na exibição de uma imagem com o nome acentuado na pasta

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Pessoal estou atualizando um projeto de um cliente que foi feito originalmente em vb.net e estou passando para o Laravel 5.1. Ta tudo certo somente um problema com a exibição de certas imagens que tem no nome da pasta algum caracter acentuado. Exemplo:

```
<img src="uploads/marcas/Imóveis/2013/5/s5erntjnoiorawwuegltdjfv000.jpg">
```

Se eu renomear a pasta Imóveis para Imoveis sem o acento e altrar o caminho para

```
<img src="uploads/marcas/Imóveis/2013/5/s5erntjnoiorawwuegltdjfv000.jpg">
```

funciona certinho. Mas como são muitas mas muitas pastas com nomes acentuados gostaria de ver se tem algum jeito disto funcionar sem eu ter que renomear as pastas.

Obrigado

Comment: Apesar do trabalho que dá, renomear seria uma boa. Acentos e espaços em _path_ e URL geralmente são fonte de dor de cabeça e perda de tempo. Seria bom evitar as maiúsculas também.

Comment: Concordo com o @Bacco, seria uma boa definir um padrão para o nome dos diretórios inclusive.

Comment: Uma possível solução seria fazer um script para renomear os arquivos automaticamente para você.

Comment: Nome de arquivos com acento impedem o download do arquivo, ou seja o IE e o Chrome retornam com erro.

Comment: Concordo com @Bacco, o problema é que são muitas pastas e como o site já estava pronto seria muito complicado fazer isto a esta altura do campeonato. Espero conseguir alguma outra solução caso contrário terei que repensar sobre como fazer para renomear e vincular ao banco de dados. Por enquanto obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você já tentou usar a síntaxe {!! !!} do Blade para garantir que a variável não passe por html escape?

Comment: Ja tentei sim. E não da certo. A unica solução mesmo sera a sugestão do @Bacco.